mysql current_timestamp format as MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS ? in an insert into? VBNET
I might want to insert the current date time into a MySQL datetime column using the format as described in the question title.
Not as YYYY-MM-DD
I don't know if this is done or your supposed to format the date read from the DB put into a listview formatted the way you want it to appear.
Now, when I read my DB to display in a list view the column it shows how I want it to look which is this
1/15/2015 11:42:47 AM
My reader line is not doing any formatting '"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")) '2
LItem.SubItems.Add(RDR("unDateTime").ToString())
So it just happens to display the way I like.
If I have to format the datetime string, how can I do that with the reader line?
looking for information
